# Android sqlite query multiply with the edit text integers?

Tags: android, sqlite

```
protected void cal() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Company obj1 = new Company();
    String val1 = obj1.getCompanyID();
    edite.getText().toString();

    Cursor sumw = dbObject.rawQuery(
            "SELECT sum(Volume)FROM SHARE WHERE _id2 LIKE ?",
            new String[] { "%" + val1 + "%" });
    sumw.moveToFirst();
    editT.setText(sumw.getString(0));
}
```

**i want to get the value of the EditText value, to multiply with the selected sum value of the query**

Comment: Don't you able to get text with getText() method?

Comment: yes i am getting the text value i enterd. but how to multiply the value with the value i get from the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
protected void cal() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Company obj1 = new Company();
    String val1 = obj1.getCompanyID();
    int n = Integer.parseInt(edite.getText().toString());

    Cursor sumw = dbObject.rawQuery(
            "SELECT sum(Volume)FROM SHARE WHERE _id2 LIKE ?",
            new String[] { "%" + val1 + "%" });
    sumw.moveToFirst();
    editT.setText(sumw.getString(0)*n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If they're integer values, try this:

```
int multiplierOne = Integer.parseInt(edite.getText().toString());
....
int multiplierTwo = sumw.getInt(0);
int product = multiplierOne * multiplierTwo;
editT.setText("" + product);
```